# Почему не отрабатывает INSERT при вставке в кастомную базу данных ModX

Tags: mysql, modx, insert

Набросал сниппет для ModX, работа с кастомной таблицей в БД. Сниппет разместил в шаблоне, вызывается через ajax+POST.
Проблемка - если чтение выполняется на ура (первая часть кода, case=read), то запись (вторая часть кода, case=insert) - со скрипом.
Если не ставить проверку mysql_real_escape_string, то пишет без вопросов, с этой проверкой строка вставляется, но для поля где проверка mysql_real_escape_string, это поле сохраняется пустым...
По идее коннект к базе внутри сниппета уже должен быть, в чем тогда барьер, не пойму.

По сути писать-то надо банальные строчные данные, по типу имя фамилия или емайл или домен, может есть другие проверки?

```
if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] != 'XMLHttpRequest') {return;}
if (empty($_POST['action'])) {return;}
$result = '';
switch ($_POST['action']) {
    case 'read':
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE status=1 LIMIT 100';
        $query = $modx->query($sql);
        if ($query) {
            while ($i= $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $result .= $i['id'];
            }
        }
    break;
    case 'insert':
        $item_name = (int)$_POST['item_name'];
        $item_text=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item_text']);
        $status = 1;
        $sql ="insert into `items` (item_name,item_text,status) values ('".$item_name."','".$item_text."','".$status."')";
        $stmt = $modx->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $res = 'ok';
        break;
}
if (!empty($res)) {
    die($res);
}
```

Comment: А в логах есть ошибки? попробуйте посмотреть сформированный запрос: `$res = $stmt->toSQL();` вместо `ok`

Comment: ошибка 500 в консоли браузера

Comment: поправил пост - строка вставляется, но для поля где проверка mysql_real_escape_string, это поле сохраняется пустым. ваш код вставил - не приходит ответ вообще.

Comment: Сторите в __логи сервера__.

Comment: лог ошибок пустой.. ошибок по сути-то нет - строка ведь записывается в базу.

Comment: Ошибка 500 не на пустом месте же возникла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось сделать через `$sth->bindValue(':item_name', $item_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);`